# Customizing fancybox 2

Tags: php, javascript, fancybox

I'm developing a wordpress theme using fancybox2 to view portfolio items. I have been able to pull the description of each image and concatenate it with the image title to display in fancybox. I have been able to also add the permalink to this string (title) so it reads as below:

Item 1/10 TITLE DESCRIPTION http://mydomain.com

The following is the documented JavaScript to display the above

```
$('.myfancybox').fancybox({
            some variables called ...

            afterLoad : function() {
                this.title = 'Item ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
            }
        });
```

I would like to be able to split the string (title) into 3 Javascript variables before outputting the final title so I can use the permalink part as an actual link rather than plain text. I can easily add any delimeters using PHP so the JavaScript can slpit it.

end result would look something like the following:

```
Item 1/10 <strong>TITLE</strong> <em>DESCRIPTION</em> <a href="PERMALINK">complete story</a>
```

I understand I'd probably need to loop through looking for the delimiter but my attempts have not been working so far.

Any help would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, I guess you should include the `php` variables directly into the `javascript` rather than into the string `title` so you shouldn't have to add any additional split code.

Have you tried something like:

```
afterLoad : function() {
this.title = 'Item ' + (this.index + 1) + '/' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' <strong>' + this.title + '</strong> ' : ' ') + '<em><?php echo category_description( $category_id ); ?></em> <a href="<?php echo "<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ?>">Complete story</a>';
}
```

assuming that you have passed in your link just the `title` like

```
<a class="myfancybox" title="<?php get_the_title() ?>" ....
```

I guess you will get the same result as passing the variables through the string (`title`) but with a little bit less `javascript` code

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JFK, unfortunately the PHP part is in a foreach loop which generates the title, description, permalink to the full article etc for each thumbnail (within an <a href> to the full sized image).